# Можно ли написать такую функцию, которая будет вызываться из JS и из C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Я пишу на C# в Asp.Net MVC. У меня есть различные компоненты: диалоговое окно, прогресс бар, спойлер и т.д. Я их добавляю с помощью html хелперов, но также мне их часто приходится добавлять на страницу динамически из JS,  .

Мне не нравится то, что я дублирую код с C# в JS. Можно ли это как-то исправить? 
Написать такую функцию, которая будет вызываться и из JS и из C#.

Возможно есть какой-нибудь компилятор, который компилит TypeScript одновременно и в JS и в C#? Или какие-нибудь другие способы?

Comment: Приведите пример что должна эта функция делать.

Comment: Возвращать string в зависимости от аргументов.

Comment: Выводите хелпером вызов функции JS.

Answer (score 2):

Единого языка для клиента и сервера в случае ASP.NET MVC нет. Такой бонус на проверенных временем платформах существует только для JavaScript в форме Node.js (собственно, киллер фича сей штуковины).

Для .NET есть разной степени сырости компиляторы JS. На данный момент активно развивается [Blazor](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor), полагающийся на Mono и WebAssembly для написания SPA полностью на C#. Но вообще есть [компиляторы для JS на базе DLR и наоборот компиляторы из IL в JS](https://www.google.ru/search?q=.net+js+compiler), которые просто позволят выполнить JS в рантайме .NET или наоборот безо всяких революций.

Вариантов много, сам не пользовался, так что с выбором конкретного компилятора не помогу.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать Microsoft Script Control Library для выполнения Javascript на сервере. Правда, она на самом деле выполняет JScript, а не Javascript, но суть та же. Чтобы это работало, группа приложений в IIS должна быть настроена на работу в 32-битном процессе.

```
//Reference: COM -> Microsoft Script Control Library
public static string ExecuteJS(string code,string function,params object[] argv)
{
    MSScriptControl.ScriptControl sc = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControl();
    sc.Language = "JScript";
    sc.AddCode(code);
    object result = sc.Run(function, argv);
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Использование на сервере:

```
public const string MyFunction = "function PrintSum(a,b){return a+' + '+b+' = '+(a+b);};";

public static string Func()
{
    return ExecuteJS(MyFunction,"PrintSum",1.1,2.2);
}
```

Использование на клиенте:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    @(new System.Web.HtmlString(MvcApplication1.MyClass.MyFunction)) ;
    document.write(PrintSum(1.1,2.2));
</script>
```

Comment: `<% =... %>;` — эм, это не Razor

Comment: @АндрейNOP ОК. Суть то не меняется.